# Save a MySQL binary field to disk with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I'm trying to retrieve the content of a MySQL Binary field with PHP and save it to the disk, but when I try to open my image file, I get this error : "The file “a.jpg” could not be opened. It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize."

Note : **I'm using Mac OS X.**

Here is the code I started :

```
function extractImages(){

    global $co;
    $query = $co->query("SELECT id, singleSRC FROM tl_events");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($query)){

        $file = $row->id;

        // Save it to the Images folder
        $path = "images/".$file;
        $ressource = fopen($path, "wb") or die("Unable to open ".$path."<br>");
        fwrite($ressource, $row->singleSRC) or die("Unable to write in the file");

    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: It looks like you are successfully saving a binary file to disk with no extension. Is your actual question "How do I determine file type based on the binary data of that file?"

Comment: Yes exactly ! Sorry if my post was not clear, I'm going to edit it

Comment: Do you have access to the `file` utility? It can make an educated guess, but it's not 100% reliable. You should be saving the filename or at the very least MIME type of your data when persisting it.

Comment: No I don't know what this file utility is. Yes I wish I could have done it but I'm just migrating the data from this database to another, I'm not the one who created this database

Answer (score 0):

I retrieve the file extension, but still can't open the generated file ("The file “a.jpg” could not be opened. It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize.")

Note : I'm using Mac Os X

Anyone has a solution ?

Thanks